# ORA-01843: not a valid month on a check constraint

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to put a Check constraint on a born date in a range of date time because I don't want to let the user insert a value < of 01-JAN-1900.

I'm trying to elabourate this as :

```
CONSTRAINT  BORN_VALIDITY   CHECK(BORN_DATE > TO_DATE('01-GEN-1900','DD-MON-1900'));
```

I also altered the date format session in the beginning with

```
ALTER SESSION NSL_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

but I'm receiving the same error with no pity from Oracle SQL.

There is some other way to set a date range on my check constraint?

Comment: If you want to use localised names, you can't rely on system default language.

Comment: If you insist to use `TO_DATE` function you can use `TO_DATE('01-GEN-1900','DD-MON-1900', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = Italian' )`. However, using `DATE` literal I would consider as the better solution.

Comment: You must also set the language: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'Italian';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the language of your DB is Italian, or whatever language in which you can write January as GEN, you should use `TO_DATE('01-GEN-1900','DD-MON-YYYY')`.

To have a solution that works no matter the language, you could better use the ANSI standard `date '1900-01-01'`

Comment: I'm already using the TO_DATE('01-GEN-1900','DD-MON-YYYY') in the check condition. I tried with the ANSI standard and it works, but if i set the check condition with a date format type different from my DATE format  ( Example : I'll insert into BORN_DATE values '01-GEN-1990', will this date format be checked in the check condition ?

Comment: The code you posted is `TO_DATE('01-GEN-1900','DD-MON-1900')`, with `1900` instead of `YYYY`. Also I'm assuming that the column has  `date` or `timestamp` type: the format you use to write a date value does not affect how the value is internally stored.

Comment: thank you, i just figured it out ; it doesnt matter how i declare my TO_DATE into che check constraint, it will just work whatever i'll insert, thank you veyr much for giving me the correct answer on ANSI format.